# knockout.js boolean virtual element vs css binding performance

Tags: javascript, performance, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Which method below of hiding an html element has the most performance gain and why?  Any consequences of using one over the other?

**CSS**

```
<div id="toolbar" class="hidden navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" data-bind="css : { hidden: !members.eventSchedule.hideSettings() }"></div>
```

**Virtual Element**

```
<!--ko if: members.eventSchedule.hideSettings()-->
<div id="toolbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: not sure about performance, but using css visibility keeps the element within the DOM, but using the virtual elements will actually remove the contained block from the DOM if the `if` check resolves to false. Having a lighter DOM could affect responsiveness overall if there are fewer elements to render.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say using "visible" binding will be much faster (yours is css, i don't know the reason why but maybe you will apply another class to make it hide). Is it because the element is always in the DOM, unlike the "if" binding in which the browser engine needs to add/remove into the DOM depending on the update value.

One trade off I can think of is if your using "if" binding you need to use delegated events for the elements that are reattached to the DOM.